# LDAP DirContext search - Perl to Java, returns different object models

Tags: java, perl, ldap, jndi

I refer to this piece of code at CPAN to execute a search in LDAP. When I run this script, I am able to see the object model; also, the model is the same for every user I search for.
[Net::LDAP::Examples](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::LDAP::Examples#OPERATION-Generating-a-SEARCH)

**Object model retrieved using Perl script:**
objectClass: top
             person
             organizationalPerson
             user
cn: someuser
sn: user
title: ENGINEER.SOFTWARE ENGINEERING
itDescription: Business Intelligence - DIS56
whenCreated: 20130419212146.0Z
whenChanged: 20190819042554.0Z

Now I'm writing Java code to make the LDAP connection using JNDI, and here, I'm not able to see attributes like itDescription and title; also, the model is different between each user I search for - attributes missing or in excess.

**Object model retrieved using JNDI:**
[objectCategory]=[CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=tester,DC=com]
[whenCreated]=[20130419212146.0Z]

Can someone please tell me why this is so? Here is my code to connect and search -

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ds.tester.com:3268");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, uName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pwd);
    DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);

    SearchControls cons = new SearchControls();
    cons.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    NamingEnumeration <SearchResult> srch = context.search("ou=employees,dc=tester,dc=com","sAMAccountName=someuser",cons);
```

This is the relevant Perl script -

```
$ldap = Net::LDAP->new("ds.tester.com") or die "$@";
    print "User : "; my $user = <STDIN>; chomp($user);
    my $passwd = <STDIN>; chomp($passwd);
    my $userToAuthenticate = "cn=$user,ou=employees,dc=tester,dc=com";
    $mesg = $ldap->bind("$userToAuthenticate",password => "$passwd",version => 3 );
    my ($ldap,$searchString,$attrs,$base) = @_ ;
    if (!$base ) { $base = "DC=tester,DC=com"; }
    if (!$attrs ) { $attrs = ['sAMAccountName' ]; }

    my $result = $ldap->search (base    => "$base",
                    scope   => "sub",
                    filter  => "$searchString",
                    attrs   =>  $attrs
                    );

    foreach $entry ($result->entries) { $entry->dump; }
```